# What's the best approach to editing/process audio in React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, audio, audio-processing

My goal is to able to add multiple tracks from various sources (record live audio, get existing MP3 files or external sources) and be able to overlay them, edit each mp3 file individually such as the pitch/frequency and etc.. My main problem at the moment is finding a library in react-native to be able to process the audio.

I've had different ideas such as trying to use [tone.js](https://tonejs.github.io/) but the problem with tone.js is that it's built on top of web audio api which only supports browsers and not IOS/Android - I believe...

I'm not too sure what the best approach is to be able to edit audio but potentially to create some sort of an audio processing engine for React Native. I'd love your opinion to get any insight on how I can move forward with audio processing.

N.B. I'm not looking for an audio player as I have seen in other posts.

TL;DR: Need help with audio processing in React Native

Comment: I am very much looking for the same thing. Has there been any progress?

Comment: @Anathapindika Did you guys ever find a package that works?

Comment: @Ryker sadly no - it's a mystery to me why this doesn't seem to exist. Please let me know if you find something.

Comment: @Anathapindika So far the only method I've found is `ffmpeg` but the learning curve seems to be pretty high

Comment: I'm also rather surprised no paid APIs for this exist

Comment: this is such a pain, and yeah no luck even finding a paid service yet